# I have two buttons, when I select one and then want to select the other, I want the first one to get unselected

Tags: swift, button, uibutton

I have done two buttons in Swift by code.
Now I want them to become selectable and then when I select the first one, it gets selected but when I select the second one, the first one gets unselected and the second one gets select normally. Then when I select the first one again, the second one gets unselected.

Comment: Sounds like you want a UISegementedControl to me. Either that, or a UISwitch. Without more context, why not use one of these? Users have been using them since 2007 and understand them intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

In the IBAction of first button:

```
buttonOne.isSelected = true
buttonTwo.isSelected = false
```

In the IBAction of the second button:

```
buttonOne.isSelected = false
buttonTwo.isSelected = true
```